# What band's logo is this picture a reference to?

Tags: identify-this-band

What band's logo is this? I've seen it in the movie *Zootopia* but cant remember what the original band name is.

[image]

Comment: Does the film have a reference to the band at all other than the logo ? is it just to tease the audience ?

Comment: Looks like some 80's hard or glam rock's logo parody.

Comment: Metallica's *Ride the Lightning* logo ?

Comment: It's definitely a parody.  Several 80's Metal bands had triangular logos, including Van Halen, Quiet Riot, Stryper and Def Leppard.  But I agree with Yorik's answer; it does appear to be influenced by Far Cry 3 a bit.

Comment: Just googling `born feral` gives some good results https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&source=hp&q=born+feral&oq=born+feral&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1.1379.2793.0.4113.11.10.0.0.0.0.123.763.9j1.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.10.760.0..46j0i131k1j0i46k1j0i10k1.0.Gq63M2gVU2c

Answer (score 2):

Band: **NEW MODEL ARMY**

Song: Born Feral

With reference to the context of the movie Zootopia

> Look for "Born Feral" on the signpost!

[image]
[image]

About the song (some personal opinion): To simply put -- a great song by a legendary band, NMA has managed to released two great albums in a row (Winter + Between Dog&Wolf) 30+ years AFTER their first release and sound just as fresh and relevant as they did back then!

But again no formal connections can be established between the logo spotted in the movie and the song itself, it's just a feeling that the song perfectly fits the mentioned context of the animals escaping captivity and enjoying their free wild spirits.

> Url to the audio:
>   youtu.be/CPCyAAryQNA

Comment: The Born Feral's logo doesn't look at all at the [New Model Army's logo](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=NEW+MODEL+ARMY&hl=fr&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR6tTSuN3UAhVMnRoKHSf7DGYQ_AUICygC&biw=1114&bih=720#hl=fr&tbm=isch&q=NEW+MODEL+ARMY+logo)... at all.

Answer (score 1):

The only logo/graphic I can think of that this *might* refer to id the cover of the album ['Knights of the new thunder' by 'TNT'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_the_New_Thunder).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks less like an album cover style and more an 80s VHS style.

The closest actual image I can find is for *Far Cry 3 Blood Dragon*, a 2013 video game that is some sort of parody of 80s action films. They were attempting to capture the feel of low budget credit sequences and bad TV interstitials etc. but the majority of things like this are from 2010-2015. So start your search there, but you may simply be responding to the look. There are very similar stock images under "80s retro style" as well.

It is a retro style that never actually existed. Real 80s stuff was more like, well, make a list of everything bad about these parodies, and then pick 2 to use. And the cheap 80s stuff was often not even 4-color process to save money.

[image]